# Run gradle static analysis plugins bug exclude unit tests

Tags: java, gradle, static-analysis

I am using some static analysis plugins (spotbugs, pmd) attached to my gradle build. They run automatically when you run `gradlew check` or something that depends on `check`.

I am trying to find a way to run JUST the parts of `check`, but exclude unit tests, in a command. Since `check` depends on `test`, I am not sure how to do this, if it's possible.

I have a large number of java / android modules and it takes a long time to do a full build with tests and static analysis, so I want to break them up as separate tasks on separate CI systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
./gradlew check --exclude-task test
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line)

Comment: Alternatively use the shorthand notation `-x test` to exclude the task `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the task `check` with excluded task `test` as proposed by Dave, you can simply create a new task and add dependencies on all tasks that perform static analysis:

```
task staticAnalysis {
    dependsOn 'spotbugsMain'
    dependsOn 'pmdMain'
}
```

You may then call `./gradle staticAnalysis`.